# Spark SQL Data Warehousing

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

I've two datasets, as shown below -

Historical:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+
|prod_id|prod_cd|  prod_desc|
+-------+-------+-----------+
|  42546|Firefox|Firefox 4.0|
|  12432| Chrome| Chrome 1.0|
+-------+-------+-----------+
```

Current:

```
+-------+-------+----------+
|prod_id|prod_cd| prod_desc|
+-------+-------+----------+
|  53243|     IE|    IE 2.0|
|  12432| Chrome|Chrome 1.5|
+-------+-------+----------+
```

I want to run a (spark) sql query on the two tables (dataframes) and get all the historical and the new entries where a common between both will pick from the latest table and remove the old table (similar to update those respective rows).

So, my output table should be like -

```
+-------+-------+-----------+
|prod_id|prod_cd|  prod_desc|
+-------+-------+-----------+
|  42546|Firefox|Firefox 4.0|
|  53243|     IE|     IE 2.0|
|  12432| Chrome| Chrome 1.5|
+-------+-------+-----------+
```

I did it for reconciliation jobs during incremental/delta loads after the initial load is done on day 0, but since a long time I've no touch with Data Warehousing and hence lost that clarity.

Do I need to use rank function after union? Or is there a better/faster approach? A help would be highly obliged.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists` with `union` :

```
select prod_id, prod_cd, prod_desc
from Current c
union all
select prod_id, prod_cd, prod_desc
from Historical h
where not exists (select 1 from Current c1 where c1.prod_id = h.prod_id);
```

Sort *word* of understanding :

With the preceding query this would return first `Current` data and then return `Historical` data (i.e. data which are not present in *current* ) with help of *correlated* `subquery`.

So, this would return *two* result sets which combined via set operator `UNION ALL` to produce desired result.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick revert, wanted to know, what is the inner query doing, it just returns the number of 1's depending on the number of common prod_id's.

Comment: @AakashBasu. . . There is no any `inner query`  perhaps you are talking about correlated `subquery` .

Comment: Yes, I mistakenly wrote inner query. Can you explain the correlated subquery with a bit more granularity? I mean, it just returns the number of 1's depending on the number of common prod_id's. But what is the where clause going to ensure here?

Comment: @AakashBasu. . . The `where` clause ensures `prod_id`s which are available in `Current` with match of `Historical` & now the `NOT EXISTS` just exclude the rows or `prod_id` which are matching with `where` clause. So, it would rewrite as `exists (select 1 from Current c1 where c1.prod_id <> h.prod_id);`

Comment: And hence, while unioning the historical portion, it will avoid for all those IDs which are there in the current as that is priority, right? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the question you have posted, using rank will not make sense because there is no column which indicates a row to be new. For example a timestamp.

So for the case you have mentioned, you can use the merge logic.

You know the table which has the newest data and the table which has the historical data. So your logic should be to merge both the tables.

Below is one way you can do in Spark SQL

```
select
case when(c.prod_id is null) then h.prod_id else c.prod_id end as prod_id,
case when(c.prod_id is null) then h.prod_cd else c.prod_cd end as prod_cd,
case when(c.prod_id is null) then h.prod_desc else c.prod_desc end as prod_desc
from historical h
full outer join current c on
h.prod_id = c.prod_id
```

If data exists in the **current** it will extract from **current** or else it will extract from **historical**. I have joined the tables on the primary key "prod_id".

Hope this helps!!